# Jackson deserialize json Map - Map<String,Map<String,String>> as one Object

Tags: java, android, jackson

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "Live": {
        "Saerro (AU)": {
            "status": "low",
            "age": "00:01:17"
        },
        "Connery (US West)": {
            "status": "medium",
            "age": "00:02:26"
        }
    }
}
```

So the Map Live has `Map<String,Map<String,String>>` as its values.
I need to deserialize Live into a list of objects,e.g.

```
public class Status implements Serializable {
    @JsonProperty
    public String name;
    @JsonProperty
    public String status;
    @JsonProperty
    public String age;
}
```

Is there an annotation or something I can use, so that the Map Key,and values get deserialized into one object?

Comment: No, what you have is an object with a field `Live` that is a `Map<String,SomeObject>` where `SomeObject` has two fields; `status` and `age`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to write a custom deserializer to handle this.  [This](http://blog.palominolabs.com/2012/06/05/writing-a-custom-jackson-serializer-and-deserializer/) gives a decent overview, and there are a number of other questions on stackoverflow that cover this, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553051/setting-up-json-custom-deserializer).

Alternatively, you could let Jackson deserialize in to a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` and then post-process it in to whatever form you wish.