# Jackson - how to send byte value as char in json sting

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to deserialize this json string

{"value":"Y"}

to this object

```
public class Data {
    byte value;

    public byte getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(byte value) {
        this.value = value;
    }       
}




ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Data data =  mapper.readValue(js, Data.class);
```

it works when in json string I put an ascii code
{"value":89}

But I want to use char value.

Main problem is that Data class is legacy class, and I can't add `@JsonDeserialize` annotation inside it.

Any other option?

Comment: Create a new class with needed types and wrap legacy class in it.

Comment: You have to use something else than ``Data`` because that is what limits the type to ``byte``.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting up JSON custom deserializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553051/setting-up-json-custom-deserializer)